# Javascript wont run in SAFARI browser

Tags: html, safari, jscript

Javascript enabled on browser settings already.
no error showing on safari developer menu.
i dont know if it is because of the audio files var audiojwanwav.

```
        function Play()
        {           
            //play sound
                var audiojwanwav = new Audio('wavfiles/jyanmp3.mp3');
                audiojwanwav.play(); 
           document.getElementById('play').setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
            if (!timeOn)
            {
                timerOn = 1;
                Loop();          
            }    
            var x = document.getElementById("stop");
            var y = document.getElementById("play");
            if (y.style.display === "block") {
                x.style.display = "block";
                y.style.display = "block";
            } else {
                y.style.display = "block";
                x.style.display = "block";
            }  
            /*ENABLE BUTTON*/ 
           document.getElementById('rps').removeAttribute('disabled'); 
           document.getElementById('rps1').removeAttribute('disabled');
           document.getElementById('rps2').removeAttribute('disabled');  
           return false; 
        }
```